# What would it look like if you cut the tardis in half?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

If you cut the tardis in half from top to bottom or left to right would you still be able to look inside it? Like from the outside? would it still work? would it destroy the universe? Assuming you have a tool that could actually cut it.

Comment: Unless something drains the artron energy it would rip a whole in the universe; see also **The Doctor's Wife**.

Comment: I'm gonna go with *"really weird"*

Comment: In `The Name of the Doctor` the Doctor says, a broken T.A.R.D.I.S. starts to "leak dimensions" (_whatever that means_). Now, if that is true, a T.A.R.D.I.S.  which is cut in half - which _IMHO_ can easily be called broken - will leak dimensions immediately. Now, since the T.A.R.D.I.S. has a number of infinite dimensions, my wild **guess** (the reason this is a comment, not an answer is it is opinion based) would be that the effect would be like a reverse big bang. An eruption of practically empty space expanding at the hearth of our universe with the speed of light.

Answer (score 3):

The TARDIS is broken into pieces in the story "Frontios" (as well as earlier in "The Mind Robber," although that one might be meaphorical).  The upshot is that everything except the control room becomes totally inaccessible.  The pieces of the control room are still around, but the rest of the TARDIS interior is missing (until the TARDIS is put back together).

An explanation for this was given in another contemporary document.  According to the *Doctor Who Technical Manual* (1983), the entrance to the TARDIS is a gateway into a separate dimension, in which the TARDIS interior lies.  *Doctor Who* has never had a strong canon, and the *Technical Manual* contains obvious errors (like putting the kaled mutant in totally the wrong part of its dalek schematic), but the dimensional gate description of the TARDIS entrance seems to be consistent with what was shown on the television show, at least in the era when it was produced.

This is specifically relevant, because in "Frontios," the Doctor needs to get a hostile alien to telekinetically pull the pieces of the TARDIS back together.  Once all the walls are pulled in around the TARDIS console, the control room is once again in a separate dimension, and this is an important plot point, because the enemy alien who reassembled the TARDIS is not able to function in this other dimension.  This is explicit and conclusive evidence that the explanation given in the *Technical Manual* was correct.

So the answer to the question is that if the TARDIS is broken apart, the pieces of the control room will exist in the regular world.  However, the TARDIS will be inoperable, and anything beyond the control room will be inaccessible until the TARDIS is reassembled.  Since merely pulling the pieces of the TARDIS back together was sufficient to recreate the link to the alternate dimension containing the TARDIS interior, the TARDIS also clearly has the ability to heal the breakages when the pieces are laid back into position.  (This is also consistent with more recent canon.)

Comment: What about the other control rooms (as seen in the episode *The Doctor's Wife*)? :-)

Comment: I have no idea.  The key feature of the control room in this case would seem to be that it is the first accessible room in the TARDIS.  (Although in some Pertwee-era stories, there appeared to be a small vestibule between the control doors and the police box doors.)  So I don't think the same role could be played by a secondary control room (such as was introduced in "The Masque of Mandragora").  Then again, in "Inferno," the Doctor showed that he could removed the console from the whole TARDIS and still dematerialize with just the console.

Answer (score -1):

It would generate a paradox.

For instance, forget about time this moment, just freeze the surrounding space and the TARDIS in time.

Now, we have just the space.

Take a dot. The dot is just an non dimentional entity.
Put infinite dots side by side, and we will get a line.
The line has one dimention, whitch is mesured by it`s width.
Take infinite lines side by side, and we will get a plane. A flat two dimensional plane, with width and height.

Take infinite planes, one above other, and a very nice three dimentional cube will appear, with width, height and depth.

We are close to TARDIS, just one more step.

With infinite cubes, one "in-out-side-beyound-above-under-etc" other, we get the four-dimentional tesseract.

That is the most likely dimentional aproximation of what TARDIS is in space, given its infinite three-dimentional-changeable-reduceable-growable rooms contained in a visible three-dimentional police phone box.

Very well. Now, let's go back to the line. For instance, if we want to slice a line, we will need one more dimention, because we need to cross the line in some point. Supose the line is aligned with the x axis, our knife would be a dot/point, like a particle, traveling all the way down the y axis, until it cross the line, and slice it in two. We will have then two lines, both formed by infinite dots.

But that is not the only way to slice the line. Oie.
Supose we can slice a dot, and it stay sliced during the smallest conceivable calculated possible part of time before it reunite again.

But remember, we froze the time, so...

If we get it`s formed dots, and for each dot slice it in two halfs, we can manually recombine them. So, all the infinite left slices go aligned to the left, forming te left slice of the line, and all the infinite right slices go aligned to the right, forming the right slice of the line.

So, different slicing method, but same results.

How to slice the (2D) plane? By analogy with the first method, with a (n-1 dimention (line)) knife going all the way down (n+1 dimention) z axis.

But then we face a problem. Not all its forming lines will be cut...
Unless we use the second method. Slice all lineses dots, reorient leftses, rightses, left lines creates left plane and right lines creates right plane.

Same result, but with all lines sliced.

Now the bigger problem.

To slice the cube, any 1D line or 2D plane could come in any 3 dimention axis or combinations of them, would make the cube cut. But this method don't cut all the planes.

And that is the reason that the second slicing method was created.

If we cut the TARDIS with the first method, only one single room will be cut, probably the command center, and slice the command center is not the same that slice the entire TARDIS. And that is one of the reasons that SHE cannot be easily attacked.

So, to slice the TARDIS we must guarantee that all TARDIS rooms must be sliced at once. So we need to cut all the dots to cut all the lines to cut all the planes to cut all the cubes or TARDIS's rooms. Only then the tesseract (TARDIS) could be cut.

But now the bigest bigger problem. Here comes the paradox.

To cut something we need movement, and there is only movement with time continuum. But with time we can't divide and reorient the dots, consequently we can't divide the TARDIS. And even TARDIS existence depends on time vortex. Without it, SHE doesn't exists, so without time, there is no TARDIS's dots to be cut.

PS: I may be wrong, but I got a lot of fun writing this essay :) Sorry about my rusty english. Polite Corrections will be welcome.

Luís

Comment: `Take infinite planes, one above other, and a very nice three dimentional cube will appear, with width, height and depth.` - Mmmm. Nope. If you take infinite planes one "above" each others, you get a 3 dimensional space. Now 3 dimensional space **can be interpreted** as a cube with edges of infinite length, but **it can also be interpreted** as as a sphere with infinite radius or a cone based on a circle with infinite radius and infinite height, or ... - you see - any spatial object with infinite dimensions.